# Trip to Matsuyama and 4-hour layover in Tokyo Narita Airport

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, nrt

I'm travelling to Matsuyama, Japan and will have a 4-hour layover in Tokyo Narita Airport. Should I pick up my checked in luggage? And can I transfer from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2 as I have to pick up the wifi device in terminal 2? Thank you

Comment: Please provide more information on which flights you're talking about.

Comment: airline: Jetstar

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is on the [official Narita Airport webpage](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/security/connection/connection_sn/). You are required to pick up your luggage before exiting to the public area, where you then must recheck them in and pass through security to get to your connection.

And I don't know what you mean by transfer, but you can travel between Terminal 2 and 3 easily. There is a [pedestrian walkway](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/access) which takes about 15 minutes each way. You can use the free [shuttle bus](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/access/shuttlebus) if want too.